# <BODY> of the views in a "scaffolded" Ruby on Rails 3 web-app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

do you know how can i modify the `<BODY>` tag of the rendered htmls files of my app's views?
I mean, i can manually edit the html, but the `<BODY>` tag is added automatic in run time... 
And i'd like to do something like

```
<body bgcolor="#0000FF">
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to edit the `application.html.erb` in the layouts subfolder of views in your application.

Of course, you'd be much better of doing this in a stylesheet rather than the markup directly :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This is the file i was searching for. However i simply can't understand why all the pages of my app have 8px padding left right ant top. Where can i change this?

Comment: Scaffolded styles are located in public/stylesheets/scaffold.css.  However, you should consider looking into using a reset.css file which removes all of the default stylings browsers impose on pages and gives you a clean slate.  I recommend checking out the blueprint.css framework for this.

Comment: And yes, you definitely want to be applying styles in CSS, not the markup.